# Does setState replace all existing data in a key, or just update what needs updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, if I have an object in state, something like:

```
{flags:
   loading: false,
   visible: true
}
```

and then call `setState({flags:{loading:true}});`, does it just update the loading flag, or does it *replace* the entire flags object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` shallowly merges current state with the new state you pass to it. If you merge

```
{
  flags: {
      loading: false,
      visible: true
  }
}
```

with

```
{
  flags: {
      loading: true
  }
}
```

the entire `flags` property will be overwritten and replaced.

But if you had another property called say `flags2` in the initial state (at the same level with `flags`), that would not be affected.